# Designing a damage system for our rules

Tags: homebrew, damage

We are designing a rule system that would better suit our tastes. The goal is to create something relatively simple, that does not get in the way of the story but still offers enjoyable game mechanisms.  Because of the strong appreciation for the AEG games (7th Sea and 5rings) we took a similar base.

The idea is that you have 4 stats (with specialties) and mages get a 5th one. The stats are ranging from 3 to 8, sometimes 10. Then you have skills, ranging from 1 to 6. And then you have for each skill you can get very specialized advanced skills that work a little bit like schools in 5rings. So they give bonuses allowing you to accomplish extraordinary feats.

The system is based on 10 side dices. You are rolling your stat and keeping your skills.
The only point we are still blocking on is the damage system. At first one of my players designed a very nice table that took into account the actual health condition of the victim, the weapon used, the strength of the user and the number of raises of success. The system was very fear and nice but required us to read a 2 pages very complex table each time you hit someone and was soon abandoned as to complicated.

Today we are thinking about something simpler. Like strength time a multiplier provided by the weapon used, from 1.5 to 4 and strength ranging from 3 – 10, with a maximum of 40 points in one blow. Raises obtained during the attack roll can be used in order to increase the damages. We are still thinking about the damage bonus you would get for one raise, for the moment it is +5 per raise. Fire arms and crossbows are getting a fixed damage score.

First we thought about a descriptive damage system, like in Kult, you get a certain wound level when the amount of damage exceeds a certain level. Wounds of the same level sum-up and after some time become one would of the next level. But one of us suggested that we could simply add the damage points as hit points.

Today an average man has 40 hit points; he is seriously wounded when he gets 20 points of damage and critically wounded at 30. You get penalties to all your actions at serious wound level and at critical. You have to roll a special resistance roll at critical level in order not to go into shock.

The only way to get more hit points is to get a specific advantage. The goal is to have a similar feeling to 5rings.

What do you think about this system, will it work and be entertaining? Do you have any suggestions? Would we need more would levels? Take more things into account?

Thank you.

Comment: Our format isn't able to support questions as yours, where you hunt for suggestions. Stackexchange specializes in finding answers to punctual problems, unlike a forum. There's a [chat] where we could talk about game design and be more open to discussion, but you need to score at least 20 reputation to be able to talk there. Answer some questions, score some points and you can join us there. Useful link: [about]

Answer (score 5):

**Playtesting is the only way to answer this.**

This will *work*, that's clear. What you're actually asking for though is, "Will we like this?" Whether you like how it works is something we can't ever answer for you. Playtest it to find out if you like the gameplay it creates.